# Find the area of the parallelogram formed by the vectors (1, 1), (1, 3).

Tags: linear-algebra

I believe the answer is 2.

the second part is the part I can't figure out.

Suppose we transform the plane (with the parallelogram in it) by multiplying by a matrix
A where det(A) = 5. Compute the area of the transformed parallelogram.

Is it just 10?

Comment: $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$

Answer (score 1):

$$A=|{\bf a}\times {\bf b}|=
\begin{vmatrix}
i&j&k\\
1&1&0\\
1&3&0
\end{vmatrix}=|2 k|=2.
$$

The second answer is also coorect as $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.